# sum values of a vector within a range -R

Tags: r

I have a vector and want to sum the individual values between each quantile. e.g.

```
v1 <- seq(0,1, 0.1)
q_v1 <- quantile(v1)
```

I can do it as `v1 %>% subset(v1<q_v1["25%"]) %>% sum()`

But is there a one line solution in r to do the partial sum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `cut` with `breaks` specifying the 'q_v1' to use as a grouping variable in `tapply` and get the `sum`

```
tapply(v1, cut(v1, breaks=q_v1), FUN=sum)
# (0,0.25] (0.25,0.5] (0.5,0.75]   (0.75,1] 
#   0.3        1.2        1.3        2.7
```